# How do I get a function to return values in adjacent cells instead of being printed below the cell where the function is written?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, transpose, google-sheets-query

I have a table of teams, names, and roles. I am trying to move that data to a separate table, but I want to write a query that returns the values in adjacent cells as opposed to directly underneath which I think is the default.

Here is a picture of the table

[image: 0]

```
=QUERY(A2:C9, "select B where A = 'Bears' and C = 'Coach'", 0)
```

// returns coach name for team 'bears'

```
=QUERY(A2:C9, "select B where A = 'Bears' and C = 'Player'", 0)
```

// returns all player names for team 'bears'

The first query achieves what I want because there is only one coach on each team to return, but the second query does not achieve what I want which is to return the values sideways to so fill in the Player1-3 columns and not impede the row beneath.

Comment: What you are looking for is a "pivot".

Comment: @daShier I looked up how to use the pivot function and selected G2:G4 and clicked "Pivot Table" in the data tab and tried inserting the selected data from G2:G4 to G2:I2 but I just got an error saying "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings."

Comment: Update your question to show your attempted pivot query and the error.

Comment: @daShier I'm not sure how to use the pivot function in a query, I followed a guide that told me to select the data and click pivot under the data tab in the toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in range **E2:I**. then...

paste in **E2** cell:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

paste in **F2** cell and drag down:

```
=FILTER(B$2:B, A$2:A=E2, C$2:C="coach")
```

paste in **G2** cell and drag down:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B$2:B, A$2:A=E2, C$2:C="player"))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Players!A:I, "select I where G = 'player' and A = "&
 QUERY(Teams!A:F,   "select A where F = '"&C2&"'", 0), 0))
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Specifically, I need to transpose this function: =QUERY(Players!A:I, "select I where G = 'player' and A = "&QUERY(Teams!A:F,   "select A where F = '"&C2&"'", 0), 0)

Comment: @BaileyPeticolas https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eXrwslzvUu0tI1NUCe_RVGqYgW9FC69yhxBVlP5mQpA/edit#gid=1328982056